# Trying to Request new pin on Admob

Tags: admob

I entered new address on admob account because on previous address I didn't get the PIN mail , now I updated my new address for requesting new PIN post , I got the following post https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3198657 regarding PIN of FAQ , but I am not getting the option of verify address on

```
Go to the Account > Payments > Payment settings page.
```

Can anyone have experience it that how I can now request the new PIN as I didn't get the post on previous address

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because help questions not on the Admob API are off topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will take time. Perhaps near around couple of weeks for the 'generate new pin' option to come so be patient. Moreover, generate new pin option is down there in the section where you enter your address verification pin. So check that as well may be you already are entitle to request new pin.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen it on the admob page as well, you can try at https://www.google.com/adsense

I know that's old question but it may help someone

Comment: Thanks man! Pin verification card was not displayed on admob however I was able to see it in adsense and request it! Both apps use the same account so doing it in one app should valid it in the other one.

Answer (score 0):

To change the Address for PIN sending destination, 
click on Account Setting that is located next to email address and publisher ID letter on Home panel, at the right corner of the page.

Then go to Payment > Payee Profile. There they are, under big letter Payee Profile there is Edit option, click Edit to change Address.